# Only monoScript show up at OnClick event in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, onclick

I have written a script which have a costume function and when I put it into the OnClick Event only monoScript show up. How to fix this?

Here is the costume function its not important what inside:
[image: Here is the costume function its not important what inside (image)]

Only monoScript shows:
[image: Only monoScript shows (image)]